# How to dynamically include Altmetric donut into resumee

Tags: luatex, html, embedding

The question has been already done here [Embed Altimetric (or Researcher ID) badges in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451232/embed-altimetric-or-researcher-id-badges-in-tex), but did not found definitive answer.

Suppose I want to embed dynamically refreshing Altmetric donuts for my publication in my CV, which is done in LuaLaTeX. Is there any way to do that?

On this page: https://api.altmetric.com/embeds.html it explains how to embed badges in html - but I was unable to understand how can I mix HTML and LaTeX in order to make it refresh when I execute my LaTeX code.

Any insight? Thanks in advance

EDIT here is an example code of the document. The donut should be included in the `%various stuff` part of the document.

```
\documentclass{cv}
\name{name}{surname}
\begin{document}

%various stuff
    
\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you include reduced, anonymized, but still compilable code for your CV to your question? That would make it easier to implement possible solutions to the embedding of the Altmetric badge, and it would ensure that such a solution actually works in your setup.

Comment: Please find attached in the edit - however in this case I don't feel that the context matters a lot, the question is how to embed dynamic updating content into a standard LuaLaTeX doc :-)